# Breaking lines in codes with mcode package

Tags: line-breaking, matlab

I want to include some code from MATLAB and I'm using the `mcode` package. But the problem I encounter with it is that it doesn't break long lines automatically and since I load the file and not the code. 
The problem will be solved if I put `...` in the end of long lines, but I wondered is there any option in this package by which long lines be broken automatically?

Revision :
here is the code :

```
‎\documentclass{book}‎

‎\usepackage{graphicx}‎ 
‎\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}‎ 
‎\usepackage{caption}‎
‎\usepackage{color,xecolor}‎
‎\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}‎

‎\begin{document}‎

‎\begin{figure}‎
‎\caption{My program for plotting the above formula in 2 different conditions}‎
‎\lstinputlisting{technique.m}‎
‎\end{figure}‎

‎\end{document}
```

where technique.m is a matlab file and what I get from that is :

[image]

and it's out of the frame. I actually get the warning that  autolinebreaks is an unknown option but I have no idea what should I do to solve the problem.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\usepackage[autolinebreaks]{mcode}`. Other possible options which may be of interest to you are `[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate.....]`. For more details, look into the source code of `mcode`.

**Edit** for the revised question.

If `autolinbreaks` option is given, `mcode.sty` defines `lstset` as (line no 231 in mcode.sty of version 2.7.0.0)

```
\lstset{breaklines=true,breakatwhitespace=true,prebreak=\usebox{\lbreakdots}}
```

The culprit here is `breakatwhitespace=true`. Your formula has no white spaces and hence it will never break at the end of line.

**Solution**

Add

```
breakatwhitespace=false
```

after loading `mcode`.

MWE will be

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
% \usepackage{color,xcolor}
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\lstset{breakatwhitespace=false} %%<---this line added

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{My program for plotting the above formula in 2 different conditions}
\lstinputlisting{technique.m}
\end{figure}

\lstinputlisting[caption={My program for plotting the above formula in 2 different
 conditions}]{technique.m}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: Instead of putting your code inside `figure` environment, you can use the second instance as I showed in the code. The differences are clear, I hope.

Comment: I actually use the autolinebreaks , but surprisingly it doesn't break the lines automatically!

Comment: @Negin: See the edit to answer.

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative is the package `Listings` ([Documentation here](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf)). It's very customizable, but for example, this would suffice I think:

```
\usepackage{listings}    
\lstset{
        language=Matlab,
        breaklines=true
    }
```

You can then embed files using `\lstinputlisting{test.m}`. With additional styling parameters, one can produce something like this (these are the contents of `test.m` compiled into .pdf):

[image: Compiled example]